# No ipa file given fastlane issue

Tags: ios, swift, continuous-integration, fastlane, cd

I have configured Fastlane for one of my iOS projects. After performing all the steps while upload build to test flight, I am getting an error saying [!] No IPA file given

Below is my fast lane file.

```
platform :ios do

  desc "Push a new release build to the App Store"
  lane :release do
    increment_build_number(xcodeproj: "XXXXX/XXXXX.xcodeproj")
    match(type: "appstore")
    cocoapods
    build_app(
      workspace: "XXXXX.xcworkspace", 
      scheme: "XXXXX_APPSTORE")
    upload_to_app_store(
      skip_waiting_for_build_processing: true
    )
    
  end

  desc "Push a new release build to the TestFlight"
  lane :beta do
    increment_build_number(xcodeproj: "XXXXX/XXXXX.xcodeproj")
    match(type: "appstore")
    cocoapods
    build_app(
      workspace: "XXXXX.xcworkspace", 
      scheme: "XXXXX_APPSTORE")
    upload_to_testflight(
      skip_waiting_for_build_processing: true
    )    
  end
end
```

> **I am running bundle exec fastlane beta in ternimal**

Please help

Comment: I also wanted to update that Fastlane is generating .ipa file in my current directory. Its without a name.

Comment: I'm having similar issue with incorrect .ipa filename. You can manually change the filename and run the fastlane upload script command. You may run $ mv oldfile.ipa newfile.ipa to update the filename.